# Need some help with making this function

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a php page where users may enter data into fields inside a form.
The form also has a picture upload utility.
This page is refreshed every time a new picture is uploaded, so to 'remember' the values the user ALREADY has filled in, I have this code:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo @$_POST['name'];?>">
```

This DOESN'T work for drop lists or radios...

I have one solution from a previous Q but that would mean I would have to create all drop lists again in PHP, when they are in HTML now, and it is ALOT of options in the drop lists.

Is there any other way?

Here is the first solution:

```
$color = $_POST["colors"];
$colors = array("red","green","blue");

<select name="colors">
<?php foreach ($colors as $option) { ?>
  <option<?php print ($option == $color) ? " selected" : ""; ?>>
    <?php print $option; ?>
  </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: Note: *don't* use `$_POST['name']` like that without any sanitizing. A malicious user could easily inject a piece of JavaScript by inputting something like `"><script>...</script>`. Use something like `htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])`.

Comment: Eh? The page is refreshed? Why don't you *not* refresh the whole page, and just add the new picture with AJAX?

Comment: @Mark Since that would introduce an unneeded dependency on JS: http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say, but you have to output valid HTML no matter how much of a pain that is.  Best suggestion is to wrap it in a helper function and include it.  Or even better, go find a good form handling library and use it.  This problem has been solved 1000's of times.

**XSS CONCERN:** Your example code has a number of security flaws.  Let me illustrate a simple way to handle a form cleanly.  The following code illustrates an error-proof way to handle:

- Reading input
- Validation
- Handling errors, with nice messages
- Re-populating the form
- Etc...

Please note the use of `htmlspecialchars` and `ENT_QUOTES` where needed.  Also, the use of the `cond ? val1 : val2` operator ensures that there are no `E_STRICT` warnings omitted, without the use of `@` (which can be terrible for performance).

```
<?php
$FirstName = trim(isset($_POST['FirstName']) ? $_POST['FirstName'] : '');
$LastName = trim(isset($_POST['LastName']) ? $_POST['LastName'] : '');
$Gender = trim(isset($_POST['Gender']) ? $_POST['Gender'] : '');

$Action = trim(isset($_POST['Action']) ? $_POST['Action'] : '');

$Errors = array();

switch($Action)
{
case 'Process':
  // validation code here
  if(empty($FirstName))
  $Errors[] = 'First Name is required.';

  if(empty($LastName))
  $Errors[] = 'Last Name is required.';

  if($Gender != 'Male' and $Gender != 'Female')
  $Errors[] = 'Gender is required.';

  if(count($Errors) > 0)
  $break;

  // save data or whatever here

  // Redirect to next page
  header('Location: nextpage.php');
  exit;
}

?>
<html>
<head>
 ...
</head>
<body>

<?php if(count($Errors) > 0) { ?>
   <div class="error">
      <?php foreach($Error as $e) { ?>
         <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($e); ?></p>
      <?php } ?>
   </div>
<?php } ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
  <p>
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($FirstName, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
  </p>

  <p>
  Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($LastName, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
  </p>

  <p>
  Gender:
  <select name="Gender">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Male" <?php if($Gender == 'Male') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Male</option>
    <option value="Female" <?php if($Gender == 'Female') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Female</option>
  </select>
  </p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to select an option at runtime, and you can control the Javascript with PHP.

Like this:

```
<?php $color = $_POST["colors"]; ?>
<script language = "JavaScript">
var colorOption = document.getElementById("<?php print($color)?>");
colorOption.selected = true;
</script>
```

Just make that script run onLoad, and set each `option` item's `id` to its value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to completely redo the list with php - just the bit that marks the current choice:

```
<select name="opts">
<option <?php if(@$_POST['opts'] == 'value1') echo 'selected="SELECTED"'; ?>>value1</option>
<option <?php if(@$_POST['opts'] == 'value2') echo 'selected="SELECTED"'; ?>>value2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

How many select boxes and radio buttons does ur form have. If the count is less than 10 u can use javascript and make it easily. Else its recommended to make your select boxes in php

PHP CODE :

```
<?php

$color = $_POST["colors"];
$colors = array("red","green","blue");

?>
<select name="colors">

<?php 
$varSelected = "";
foreach ($colors as $option) 
{ 

  if($option == $color)
  {
    $varSelected = "selected:selected";
  }
  else
  {
    $varSelected ="";
  }
?>
  <option <?php echo $varSelected?>>
    <?php print $option; ?>
  </option>

<?php 
} 
?>
</select>
```

Javasript Method : Will need form modification. You will have to add id to your option boxes which will be same as its value.

```
// supposing $_POST['colors']='Red';
<html>
<select name="gender">
<option value="Red" id="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Blue" id="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("<?php echo $_POST['colors']").setAttribute("selected", "selected");
</script>
```